# Active directory - dsmoduser to add "Other" pager number

Tags: active-directory

To update user pager information, I need to user `dsmod user -pager 2321` option. But in the GUI browser, there is also "other" option which I need to fill. How can I add anything there using command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article at Microsoft: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732954.aspx

- This command supports only a subset of commonly used object class attributes.

You will have to use something else if you wish to do this via command line. Powershell or vbs will help you achieve this.